# Crontab job than writes transition data to log file

Tags: bash, logging, networking, cron, rsyslog

I am having two computers. First "Router" have two ip address(`10.3.0.1` and `192.168.1.105` ) is looking to internet and to sub-network `10.3.0.0/28` and have `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. I also added rules to iptables to allow forwarding from `10.3.0.0/24` . Second "User" have an ip `10.3.0.14` and def route `10.3.0.1` [image] I need to create cron job which will write hourly to a log file */var/log/net-usage/10.3.0.14.log* the quantity of the transition data (upload and download). I need to use rsyslog(combined with loger), cron and iptables. Log format must be like
*Dec 31 08:23:06  Upload: 171K; Download: 8799K*

I tried to solve it using transition information from iptables -vnL

I wrote simple bash code *script.sh* and made it executable

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date '+ %h %d  %H:%M:%S')
upload=$(iptables -vnL |sed -n 11p| awk '{print"UPLOAD" " " $2 ";"}')
download=$(iptables -vnL | sed -n 12p | awk '{print "DOWNLOAD" " " $2}')
echo $date $upload $download >> /var/log/net-usage/10.3.0.14.log
```

I am having two issues. First when i am running this script from terminal ***./script.sh*** i got what i want

**Ju20 15 08:05:12 UPLOAD 1446K; DOWNLOAD 25M**

But when tried to add it to cron.  **crontab -e**

0 * * * *  /path_to_script/script.sh

I got only

**Jul 20 05:00:01**

without upload/download statistics in my 10.3.0.14.log file.

Second issue. I need to duplicate file 10.3.0.14.log from router to a user machine using rsyslog(and logger if needed). And put it to **/var/log/net-usage.log**.

Comment: Try to change iptables to `/sbin/iptables`(* in the crontab. The default path for cron doesn't usually include sbin.  *) or whatever  `type iptables` prints.

Comment: Alternatively, near the top of the crontab for this user, add a line `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin`.

Comment: To answer the second question, I refer you to https://www.tecmint.com/setup-rsyslog-client-to-send-logs-to-rsyslog-server-in-centos-7/ .  Other than that, you could of course just use `scp` to copy over a static file.

Comment: Thank you. I modified my script (/sbin/iptables), now cron understands it correctly. First issue is closed.

Comment: no scp is not an answer for me. I need rsyslog and logger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `iptables` to `/sbin/iptables`(* in the crontab. The default path for cron doesn't usually include /sbin.

*) or whatever `type iptables` prints.